# able to Select and deselect multiple elements in html and keep track of what has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML template will be appended many times depending upon the backend. So, I want to select the topics and send the id of selected elements. How to do it?
Right now I can only select and also after that i can't de-select it too. 
Help!!

My Jquery code to select:

```
$(document.body).click(function(evt){
  var clicked = evt.target;
  var currentID = clicked.id || "No ID!";

  document.getElementById(currentID).style.backgroundColor = "#00afbc";
  //$(clicked).html(currentID);
})
```

My Html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="container-<%=no%>">

    <div id="circle" style="background:<%= colorCode %>;" class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="text" style="color:<%= textColor %>;">
            <%=p ercent %>
        </div>
        <div class="percent" style="color:<%= textColor %>;">%</div>
    </div>

    <div id="sideText">
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-9 everything-checkbox">
            <!--input type="checkbox" class="toggle" /-->
            <div id="currentID">
                <%=currentID %>
            </div>

            <div id="question">
                <%=t otalQues %> Questions Attempts
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<hr style="width: 100%; color: #d9d9d9; height: 1px; background-color:#d9d9d9; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;" />
```

Comment: Where do you want to send the id of the selected elements?  To the server or another function.

Comment: for now say another function.. from there i will be able to send to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add and remove a class to keep track of the selected items and then just get all the selected items with an ID

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document.body).click(function (evt) {
        var clicked = evt.target;
        if (!$(clicked).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(clicked).addClass('selected');
            $(clicked).css('background-color', '#00afbc');
        } else {
            $(clicked).removeClass('selected');
            $(clicked).css('background-color', '');
        }
    });
});

function getSelected() {
    var ids = [];
    $('.selected').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (id) {
            ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
    return ids;
}
```

Comment: but i have to double click to select it.. i am looking into it now